# Xcode: Overlapping images with alpha

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6

Basically I have this problem:

[image]

Can I achieve this either on the Interface Builder or programmatically?

Comment: What object type are those rectangles, or are they "drawn" within the `drawRect` methods?

Comment: @trojanfoe They are UIImageViews with opaque UIImages and 0.5 alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using alpha you can not achieve this, if there is not special purpose of Alpha then set Alpha to 0 and play with solid color.